# Analytic functions over an open subset vs continuous functions over its closure

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Let $H(G)$ denote the set of analytic functions over an open subset of the complex plane $G$. Let $A(G)$ denote the collection of continuous functions over the closure of $G$. Can you provide an example of function that is in $A$ but not in $H$?

Comment: Sure, any non-constant real-valued continuous function, like $|z|$ is continuous but not analytic.

Comment: The notation $A(G)$ is sometimes used for functions that are analytic on $G$ and continuous on the closure (hence $A(G) \subset H(G)$, with $G=B(0,1)$ and $f(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}$ being an example of an element of $H(G)$ that is not in $A(G)$).